# How can I do a method like the subtotal function of excel with a multidimentional array?

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array, web-applications

I would like to do How Can I do the next sum in a multidimencional array.

I have this array:

```
         $products = array (
                     array("Id" => "000001", 
                          "Name" => "Cheese", 
                          "Quantity" => "10", 
                          "Price" => "10"),

                    array("Id" => "000001", 
                          "Name" => "Cheese", 
                          "Quantity" => "20", 
                          "Price" => "20"),

                    array("Id" => "000001", 
                          "Name" => "Cheese", 
                          "Quantity" => "10", 
                          "Price" => "30"),

                    array("Id" => "000002", 
                          "Name" => "Ham", 
                          "Quantity" => "20", 
                          "Price" => "200"),

                    array("Id" => "000002", 
                          "Name" => "Ham", 
                          "Quantity" => "9", 
                          "Price" => "100"),

                    array("Id" => "000003", 
                          "Name" => "Baicon", 
                          "Quantity" => "40", 
                          "Price" => "900")
                       );
```

I have this function that receives three parameters, these are: The array products, a variable called cond1 and another variable called cond2.

cond1 and cond2 are two keys names of the array (for example = cond1: "Id" and cond2: "Price"), I want the next:

1. I want the function to compare if cond1 and cond2 are really names of keys in the associative array ($ product). this step has done.

My problem is here:

2. If the names (cond1, cond2) are same to any the array's keys, then it must examine the values ​​in the column of cond1 of the array and look for repeated values.

for Example:

suppose cond1 = "Name", $products array has a column called "Name", for this field we have the following values: "Cheese", "Ham", "Cheese", "Ham", "Baicon", "Cheese". So I need to identify and group the values ​​that are repeated.

3. Then, suppose that cond2 = "Prince", $products array has a column called "Price", Then, I must add all the prices of the fields that are repeated in cond1

The result of add should be: for "Name" => "Cheese", "Price" => "60"

That's the idea, something like function Subtotal from Excel.

here I show the function that I have done:

```
      function SumArray ($product = null, $cond1 = null, $cond2 = nul)
                { 

        $subArray = array(); //array que se utilizara para particionar el array1, obtener 1 fila y comprobar si los nombres de las llaves que se introducen como parametros existen verdaderamente en el arreglo.

        $new_Array = array(); //array que sera retornado por esta función


        //validations
        if (!is_array($product) || empty($product)) {
        return "Exist an error with array";
        } else

        {
        $subArray = $product[0]; 

        if (empty($cond1)) {
            return "parameter 2 is empty";
        } else if (empty($cond2)) {
            return "parameter 3 is empty";
        } else { 


            if (array_key_exists($cond1, $subArray) && array_key_exists($cond2, $subArray)) {

            //foreach to sum values

            foreach($product as $item){

            if(array_key_exists($item[$cond2],$new_Array)){


            $new_Array[$item[$cond1]][$cond2] = $new_Array[$item[$cond1]][$cond2] + $item[$cond2];

                } else {

                    //if key no exist, add it

                    $new_Array[$item[$cond1]] = array($cond2=>$item[$cond2]);
                        }

            } 

            }  else {
                return "Keys doesn't exist in array";
            }

         } 
        } 

         //new array
         return $new_Array;     
             }

             $b = "Id";
             $c = "Quantity";

             $resul = array();
            $resul = SumArray($a, $b, $c); 

            echo "<br><br>";

            print_r($resul);

            echo "<br><br>";
```

this function must return an array with the new calculated values ​​at the end. However, it does not do exactly what I want, it returns this to me:

```
           Array ( [000001] => Array ( [Quantity] => 20 ) [000002] => Array ( [Quantity] => 100 ) [000003] => Array ( [Quantity] => 900 ))
```

It is not the expected result. Where can I be wrong?

the reul array should contain something like this:

```
   array([Id] => "000001", [Quantity] => "60",
```

Comment: where is the array coming from? in DB? maybe instead of doing it on a PHP level, why not do it in the database level, sum it there, so that in PHP you don't have to do stuff here and whatnot anymore, just simply fetch the values and thats it

Comment: the array comes from a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the reason why would you not do it on the DB level, but basically what you need to do (or one of the way to do it) is just to group the array and sum the particular column accordingly using the `Id`.

Use the key to group them, here's the idea:

```
$array[<id here>][<desired column here>]
```

Here is an example:

```
function sumArray($array, $index, $col) {
    $returnArray = []; // temporary container
    // sanity checks
    if (!is_array($array)) {
        return 'error not an array';
    }
    $firstRow = reset($array);
    if (!array_key_exists($index, $firstRow) || !array_key_exists($col, $firstRow)) {
        return 'error keys provided not found';
    }
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (!isset($returnArray[$value[$index]])) { // initialize
            $returnArray[$value[$index]] = [$index => $value[$index], $col => 0];
        }
        // add value
        $returnArray[$value[$index]][$col] += $value[$col];
    }

    return $returnArray;
}
```

[Sample Output](https://3v4l.org/mmOWf)

Sidenote: Just like what I've said in the comments, assuming you're using MySQL, you can just do it in that level instead of having summation in PHP. Something like this:

```
SELECT p.name, SUM(p.quantity) FROM products p
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

Then you wouldn't need to do it in PHP anymore. You'll just fetch the values and not worry of adding them.

Comment: it works perfect, Thank you. And you totally right about doing this operation in database, it's a suggestion that I'm going to take in cosider. and in this case I need to do this function, for the purposes of my project. But I'll really take your suggestions in considers, they are very valuable

Comment: Is it possible for example instead of Array
( [000001] => Array ( [Id] => 000001 [Quantity] => 40 ), print something like this: Array
( [Id] => Array ( [Id] => 000001 [Quantity] => 40 )   ? or that would be very rare and ilogic?

Comment: @RolandF you can remove the `000001` by just using `$data = array_values(sumArray($array, 'Id', 'Quantity'))`

Answer (score 1):

Given your array above, you could do something like the following:

```php
$subtotals = function($arr, $lookupCol, $sumCol) {
    $map = [];

    foreach ($arr as $index => $elem) {
        if (isset($elem[$lookupCol]) && isset($elem[$sumCol])) {
          $map[$elem[$lookupCol]] = isset($map[$elem[$lookupCol]]) ? 
                                    $map[$elem[$lookupCol]] + $elem[$sumCol] :
                                    $elem[$sumCol];
        }
    }
    return $map;
};
```

Calling the function with:

```
print_r($subtotals($products, "Name", "Price"));
```

will return the following:

```
Array
(
    [Cheese] => 60
    [Ham] => 300
    [Baicon] => 900
)
```